# Print Glossary and Bibliography as Chapter

Tags: bibliographies, glossaries

I am using the `apa6` document class with the `glossaries` and `biblatex` + `biber` packages. If I move the print statements to where I need them in the document:

```
\input{sections/introduction}
\input{sections/purpose}
\input{sections/scope}
\input{sections/definitions}

%%% Glossary Chapter %%%
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title=\normalsize\mdseries{Glossary}]

%%% References Chapter %%%
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography%[heading=bibintoc]

\input{sections/overview}
\input{sections/general_description}
\input{sections/architecture_description}
\input{sections/functional_description}
\input{sections/external_interfaces}
```

They still print at the end of the document. Is it possible to insert them at a specific place in a document as if they were just another chapter?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a compilable example (see MWE with bibliography).

Comment: TeXnician's link is [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) but make sure to also read [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Normally moving around `\printbibliography` *should* have an impact on where the bibliography appears in the document. So an example is really needed to see what is going on.

Comment: Haven't taken a look at the links yet, but I just stripped down what I had into a minimal example, and it is printing correctly. It appears that both `\printbibliography` and `\printglossary`should be appearing where they are moved. I may have asked the wrong question.